# JAVA -Getting "Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet" while accessing swagger UI

Tags: java, swagger

[refer this screenshot to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjU5w.png)** Java - Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet**

Getting this error while accessing the swagger UI. Earlier it was working fine but after upgrading Jackson-databind.jar along with its dependencies Jackson core and Jackson annotation jars from 2.10.5 to 2.13.4(also tried with versions 2.13.2.1 and 2.13.2.2)after this change unable to access swagger UI.
(I have installed my build using ocp setup so, there all the pods are up and running)

swagger jar version= 1.5.16

Logs:

[10/2/22 22:51:25:961 GMT] 00000041 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5117)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:281)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1184)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:412)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:566)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:500)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:360)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:70)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:514)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:584)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1057)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:245)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:368)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:601)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:193)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:98)
at com.ibm.cdb.api.rest.config.RespHeaderAddFilter.doFilter(RespHeaderAddFilter.java:48)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1002)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1140)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5059)
... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.JAXRSServerFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean---1032362584': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.swagger.jaxrs.ext.SwaggerExtension: Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.JaxRs2Extension could not be instantiated
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org

Comment: You are missing vital information here. Start with providing the stacktrace of your application and not a screenshot showing the error at the swagger ui.

Answer (score 0):

The swagger version was incompatible with Jackson-databind(2.13.2.1). So, updated the swagger version too.